# Image riddle good luck

Tags: cipher

You will have to decode a secret word from this image:

[image: secret word]

And then use a cipher to combine the word and decode the encoded message below
Again, good luck!

Encoded Message: Zeyd Iuhpchhpp

Answer (score 6):

1. Decode a secret word

   > Binary 01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 equals 'Hello' in ASCII table (72 101 108 108 111)
2. Use that word to decode the message

   > Using 'Hello' as a key use Vigenere cipher to decode the message: Sans Undertale

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> The image is binary (if you replace all of the blacks with 0 and whites with 1)

And

> This translates into hello